# Uncaught ReferenceError: readURL is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the src of an image element to the image uploaded in the file form, however, when I select an image, I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: readURL is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange` and the src of the image element doesn't change.

HTML

```
        <div class="new-avatar-container">
            <img class='new-avatar-picture' src='{{url("storage/uploads/profile_pictures/edited/".$user->image_file_name)}}'>
            <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                <button class="btn">Upload a new avatar</button>
                <input class='new-avatar' type="file" name="file" onchange="readURL()">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript

```
function readURL(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                $('.profile-container-picture').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $(".new-avatar").change(function() {
        readURL(this);
    });
```

Comment: `onchange="readURL()"` get rid of this inline binding.  You are already binding logically.

Comment: That is the exact order. I do have some other Javascript code as well before that but it is used for different functionality. I tried removing onchange="readURL()" and stopped getting the error but the image still does not change. The weird thing is that this was working yesterday even though I was getting the error but now it doesn't and I haven't changed anything.

Comment: How do I make sure that the elements exist?

Comment: Right before the closing </body> tag

Comment: The function is inside $(document).ready(function() {}. Could that be causing a problem?

Comment: I get 2 lines, 1 and undefined.

Answer (score 0):

if you using same function name for different , then also it occurs

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34649360)

Answer (score -1):

Try to add your function in :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   readURL = function(input) {}
});
```

perhaps your function is not present when you try to call it

Comment: functions are hoisted

Comment: while this works, it's more readable to explicitly assign a global to window, like `window.readURL= ...`